# Show page only once after sign up - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that is using Devise, I would like that after a user signs up, they are directed to a specific page, this page calls an API and saves the value from the API, I need this page to only be accessible or available after a user completes the sign-up form and clicks submit, and is then redirected to this page.

I do not want this page or URL accessible any other way but after sign-up, as the API will send a new value if accessed again. How can I accomplish this?

Once a user signs up they will be redirected to the page calling the API:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  api_call_path ##path that can only be accessed after sign_up
end
```

The API is called and the response from the JSON data is automatically saved to the database once the page is opened, if the page gets opened again a new JSON response will be received with new data, which is what I would like to avoid.

**So in a nutshell, my question is how can I restrict access to a specific path, and only make that path accessible if a user completes the sign-up form (devise) OR is there a way that I can run the code from the controller using a callback/filter after the user is created through the User model?**

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors, does this api call require any input from the user? The more concrete details you can provide the more useful answers you will get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just busy with something similar. You do not need to direct the user to a page to run the code, you can just run the code that needs to be run after the user logs in the first time.

You need to create a Session Controller, and create a conditional statement that checks if the user has logged in previously:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "sessions" }

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.sign_in_count == 1
       ##Do something awesome
    else
       root_path
    end
  end
end
```

As Emmanuel advised you can check futher info on the [Devise Controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the moment between after sign_up and showing the specific page - state A. So in the specific page controller you need to know - is the user in state A. You can achieve it by

1) saving to db (server side) that user is in state A after sign up and resetting state after showing specific page (you can do resetting triggered by client side to guarantee that page is showed).

2) saving to cookies (client side) after sign up then do as above.

Second solution is more clean in my opinion, but I do not know how strict is the rule to show only once

Comment: The cookie can be destroyed by the user at any time. Do not trust cookies.

Comment: @max thats why I considered the importance of once show rule. If it is only "welcome" page I see no harm in showing it too user that is purposely want to see it again by deleting cookie

Answer (score 0):

You can customize devise users controller by issuing

```
rails generate devise:controllers [scope]
```

Then customise UsersController such that after user is saved you can call your api code there
eg

```
def create
  @user = ....
  if @user.save
    @user.call_api_method()
  else
    ......
  end
end
```

For more information check [Configuring controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)